# Data type support in ColdFusion querynew()

Tags: coldfusion, casting, apache-poi

Does anyone know of a way to store values as NVARCHAR in a manually created query in ColdFusion using the querynew() function?  I have multiple parts of a largish program relying on using a query as an input point to construct an excel worksheet (using Ben's POI) so it's somewhat important I can continue to use it as a query to avoid a relatively large rewrite.

The problem came up when a user tried storing something that is outside of the VARCHAR range, some Japanese characters and such.

Edit: If this is not possible, and you are 100% sure, I'd like to know that too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a ColdFusion query with queryNew(), you can pass a list of datatypes as a second argument.  For example:

```
<cfset x = queryNew("foo,bar","integer,varchar") />
```

Alternatively, you can use cf_sql_varchar (which you would use in queryparam tags).  According to the livedocs, nvarchar is accepted for the CF varchar data type.

[QueryParam livedoc (referenced for nvarchar data type)](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=part_cfm.htm)

[QueryNew livedoc (referenced for data type definition)](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000600.htm)

[Managing Data Types livedoc (referenced for using cf_sql_datatype)](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00001270.htm#1182700)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I've been able to come up with so far is this:

```
<cfset x = QueryNew("foobar")/>
<cfset queryAddRow(x) />
<cfset querySetCell(x, "foobar", chr(163)) />
<cfdump var="#x#">
```

When dumped, this query does contain the British Pound symbol.

I haven't tried this with Ben's POI utility, but hopefully it helps you some.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using JavaCast() to set the values, as shown here:
[Kinky Solutions (Ben Nadel) on JavaCast()](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/291-QueryNew-JavaCast-And-Notes-About-Data-Type-Translation.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're [using Unicode end-to-end](http://mysecretbase.com/ColdFusion_and_Unicode.cfm).

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much all you need:

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="utf-8">
```

ColdFusion (& java) stores string in UTF-8 by default.  All you need is to tell CF that the encoding of the page is UTF8.  The alternative way is to save the Byte-order mark (BOM), but Eclipse/CFEclipse doesn't do it.